# Approximation Rates for Multivariate Taylor Series

Tags: polynomials, approximation-theory, constructive-mathematics, taylor-series, growth-rate

Let $k,n,m$ be positive integers and suppose that $f$ is $C^{k}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ functions.  For any given $\epsilon>0$ and $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$, are there known sharp approximation rates for
$$
\inf_{\beta_{\cdot} \in \mathbb{R}}\,\sup_{\|x-x_0\|\leq \epsilon} \,
\left\|
f(x) - \sum_{|\alpha|\leq d} \beta x^{\alpha}
\right\| \leq R(k,\epsilon,n,m,d)
$$
where $R$ is independent of $f$?  Herefore, I index $\beta$ depending on all multivariate monomials's exponents of degree at-most $d$

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130684/multivariate-polynomial-approximation-of-smooth-functions/130747#130747