# Multivariate Jackson inequality for Chebyshev approximation

Tags: asymptotics, approximation-theory, multivariable-calculus

There is an approximation of a multivariate function by a Chebyshev polynomial of degree n. One needs to understand how the approximation error behaves depending on the degree of the polynomial or express the degree of approximation in terms of the error. There is an understanding of how to estimate the approximation error using Jackson's inequality, Markov's, or Bernstein's inequality for one variable. How to estimate these errors in a multivariate case? Is Jackson's inequality applicable to non-trigonometric series? What are the formulas/theorems for estimating the error in the approximation of functions of several variables?

[Chebyshev approximation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0ua0.png)

[Univariate Jackson inequality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeBma.png)

Comment: Is this helpful? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130684/multivariate-polynomial-approximation-of-smooth-functions/130747#130747

Comment: @MargaretFriedland Thank you for the help. I found another formulation:[![best polynomial](https://i.postimg.cc/MTH3JZ0g/mul-jackson-cond.png)](https://postimg.cc/DJVPqTMc), multivariate Jackson theorem takes the form [![bound](https://i.postimg.cc/j2bbxJ8L/mul-jackson.png)](https://postimg.cc/mz8qVhWs). If I understand correctly, this is an estimate of the best polynomial approximation from the set of all polynomials of degree n. And your version gives an estimate for a given polynomial. There is also a difference on the right side of the inequality in how partial derivatives are taken.